# Do MERGE query in java neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

I have users 1 and 7 and I want to merge a relationship friend between them.The cypher query works fine but when i try to write it in java it is not working

how to do this cypher query using java:

```
         MATCH (a:user), (b:user)
         WHERE a.ID="1" AND b.ID="7"
         Merge (a)-[:friend]->(b)
         return a, b
```

I tried to this but it is not working

```
     Result result = db.execute( "MERGE (a:user {ID:'7'})-[:friend]->(b:user {ID:'5'}) return a.ID,b.ID") )
```

also I tried this

```
 Result result = db.execute(MATCH (a:user), (b:user) WHERE a.ID='1' AND b.ID='7' Merge (a)-[: friend]->(b) return a, b)
```

Both are not working

Comment: Hi, please add all relevent information to your question: Java code snippet, exceptions, detailed information on what you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You have several Java syntax errors.

1. The first statement has an extra `)` at the end. It also needs to end with a semicolon.
2. the seconds statement needs to wrap the Cypher query in double-quotes (to be a legal Java String). It also needs to end with a semicolon.

Comment: I have tried that but it is not working, this is the full code:

Comment: try ( Transaction ignored = db.beginTx();
       Result result = db.execute( "MERGE (a:user {ID:'7'})-[:friend]->(b:user {ID:'5'}) return a.ID,b.ID") )

Comment: The `try` statement needs a code block (`{ ...}`). See [this page](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-cypher-java.html) for some sample code. [Here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.2.5/community/cypher/docs/cypher-docs/src/test/java/org/neo4j/cypher/example/JavaQuery.java) is a full example.

Comment: "MATCH (a:user {ID:'1'}),(b:user {ID:'5'})  MERGE (a)-[:friend]->(b) return a, b".      I Tried this but it is also not working

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete code snippet that should work in your case:

```
try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
    // Query, with params
    String query = "MATCH (a:user {ID: {aId}}), (b:user {ID: {bId}}) " +
         "MERGE (a)-[:friend]->(b) " +
         "RETURN a, b";

    // Params
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("aId", 1);
    params.put("bId", 7);

    // Execute in try-with-resource, to ensure that result will be closed
    try (Result result = db.execute(query, params)) {
        // read result here
    }

    tx.success();
}
```

Notable things here:

- Transaction is executed in **try-with-resource** block
- Query is using params - `{aId}` and `{bId}`
- Params are passed as `Map` with query to database
- Query ix executed in **try-with-resource** block, to ensure that resource will be closed

---

Probably you should checkout [Using Neo4j from Java](http://neo4j.com/developer/java/) developer resources, to get more examples and information on that topic.